# NLog в C#. Для чего он?

Tags: c#

Что такое NLog? Для чего он? Если можно приведите какие-то примеры

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`NLog` - это отличный помощник для нас, разработчиков, который помогает реализовать грамотное логирование действий. При внедрение его в проект, вы можете настроить сохранение указанных действий в файл, отправить на сервер или почту, либо сохранить запись в базе.

Давайте разберем простой пример:

При внедрение `NLog` в проект, вам потребуется файл конфигурации (это может быть отдельно файл `NLog.config` или можно все уместить в `App.config`).

Содержимое конфигурационного файла:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">  
<targets>
    <target name="run_log"
    xsi:type="File"
    layout="${longdate}|${level}| ${message}"
    fileName="${basedir}/Application.log"/>
</targets>
 
<rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="run_log" />
</rules>
</nlog>
```

Что мы видим?

- У нас есть одна цель (target), у которой задано действие - записать в
  файл `Application.log` строку в формате "дата|уровень|сообщение", формат можете настроить под свои нужны.
- Также у нас есть правило (rules), которое дословно можно пояснить как "если сообщение уровня `Debug` и выше, то отдать его цели `run_log`, которое в свою очередь должно записать в файл информацию".
- Как целей, так и правил может быть несколько, можно сразу записывать в файл и отправлять на сервер, либо все ошибки записывать в отдельный файл. Тут уже ваша фантазия и поставленные задачи!

Надеюсь с конфигурацией мы разобрались. Перейдем тогда к коду, добавим к примеру вот такие строки в наш проект:

```
Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
log.Trace("trace message");
log.Debug("debug message");
log.Info("info message");
log.Warn("warn message");
log.Error("error message");
log.Fatal("fatal message");
```

Хорошо, что видим тут? А все довольно просто, мы создаем некий объект `logger`, в нем есть необходимые нам методы для создания лога. Мы можем вызвать `log.Log(уровень,сообщение)` - указав нужный уровень лога, а можем вызвать под каждый уровень свой метод (как в примере).

В итоге у нас должен создасться файл `Application.log` с примерно таким содержимым:

> 2018-05-06 14:33:46.0911|TRACE|trace message
>
> 2018-05-06 14:33:46.1380|DEBUG|debug message
>
> 2018-05-06 14:33:46.1380|INFO|info message
>
> 2018-05-06 14:33:46.1536|WARN|warn message
>
> 2018-05-06 14:33:46.1536|ERROR|error message
>
> 2018-05-06 14:33:46.1693|FATAL|fatal message

Надеюсь это поможет вам в понятие такой вещи, как `NLog`, вы можете также поглядеть [данную статью](https://itvdn.com/ru/blog/article/logging-project-with-nlog-framework).